# script not executing in jsf

Tags: jsf, autocomplete

I am using an ajax request for autocomplete in jsf, I want the autocomplete suggestions to disappear once I click at any other point in website.
I am using onblur, and calling script for to change the display to none, but the script does not appear to be working.

this is the autocomplete code in my xhtml:

```
<rich:autocomplete id="test" required="true" onblur="hidebox()"                 requiredMessage="Field is blank" mode="cachedAjax"  
minChars="3" value="#{action.do.testmethod}"                    autocompleteMethod="#{action.autocomplete}">
</rich:autocomplete>
```

this is the hidebox code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function hidebox() {
          alert("Test");
          document.getElementById('test').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual id of the element is not `test`. JSF composes the ID (probably it will be `[formId]:test`) to avoid ids being repeated (more so when used in tables, lists, etc.).

You can try to do `document.getElementById('[formId]:test')...`. You can use your browser inspector utilities to check the actual Id, if you are not sure of what `[formId]` is. And you can just do `onblur="hidebox(this)"` and use directly the object in the JS function.

Comment: but even the alert is not generated on clicking anywhere else on the page, doesnt that mean that the script execution is failing?

Comment: Missed that point; I saw `JSF` and went straight to the more JSF-related issues.

Comment: another thing i want to ask is, where should the script be placed inside xhtml code? should i place it inside the head tag or inside the <f:view> tag?

Comment: I usually put them in the `h:head`, but you can but them in the body too. Think that in the end you have an HTML page (head and body)

Comment: ok i got the script working, it should be place in the view tag, and yes i do need to add the formid:iest to get the tag. Also, i used on blur event to hide the autocomplete list on clicking away, but i want the list to appear again on clicking in the box.
How do i get that?is there any specific event defined for such a case, to toggle on clicking inside and outside the box?